# What do I need to test on the iPod touch (besides the actual device)?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I've tested my iPhone app on the iPhone.  Now I want to test it on the iPod touch.  Assuming I have an iPod touch what else do I need?

I just want to make sure all the certificates and stuff that I used for the iPhone will work for the iPod touch too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificates will work fine as is. If you really want to test against a touch I would recommend using the ad-hoc method and asking one of the people who have requested support if they would like to test it. If you haven't done an ad-hoc distribution there are instruction in the portal. You may have to upload a new version only because it looks like itunes connect doesn't let you change support after the fact, probably to keep compatibility for a given version.

Answer (score 1):

You'll  have to make a new provisioning profile that has device ids for your iPhone and iPod touch. But your certs will be fine as is.